# Error using Way2SMS api for sending sms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sms

I am using Way2SMS api for sending sms from my windows form application using c# in visual studio 2010. This is my code:

```
SendSms sms = new SendSms();
string status = sms.send(textBoxId.Text, textBoxPassword.Text, richTextBoxText.Text, textBoxSendTo.Text);
if (status == "1")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Message Sent Successfully");
}
else if (status == "2")
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Internet Connection");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login Or No Internet Connection " + status);
}
```

I always get the 2nd or 3rd error case i.e., No internet connection or Invalid Login.

Do I need to grant special privileges so that the application has access to internet. please note that I already have my firewall turned off. I am using Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2010.

Using: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8d90a/send-sms-using-C-Sharp-net/

Comment: Are you using a proxy to connect to the internet?

Comment: Sir, I just connect to a Wifi router, and internet is accessible. I don't have to make any configurations, so I think no proxy is used.

Comment: Any other service to send SMS from C# in India?

Comment: You should also test with a different network connection and see if the problem is related to your current connection or with your login credentials.

Comment: Sir, I have tried with different connections. Also tried turning my firewall completely off!

Comment: Then, maybe you should check if the values of `textBoxId.Text` and `textBoxPassword.Text` are correct.

Comment: I tried replacing these values with there string equivalents. Still it did not work.

Comment: What other status codes to you receive besides `2`?

Comment: When have you created your account?

Comment: I get -1.
I created my account years ago. But I can login to my account successfully and send messages from there.